# Error LocalStrategy requires a verify callback when trying to use passport js

Tags: node.js, passport.js

This code is same to the tutorial which I am following for passport configuration. It does not got error but I am facing this:
[image: this is the error screenshot which i am facing]

This is my passport config file in which I have config my passport-local. I had use bcrypt package to secure password. This is not the main file.

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require("../model/user");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");


function init(passport){
        passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField:'email'}),async(email,password,done)=>{
            // check if email exist
            const user =await User.findOne({email:email});
            if(!user){
                return done(null , false , {message : "user doesnot exist"});
            }

             bcrypt.compare(password, user.password).then(match=>{
                 if(match){
                    return done(null , user ,{message : "logged in successfully"});
                 }
                return done(null , false ,{message : "email or password incoorect"});
                
             }).catch(err =>{
                return done(null , false ,{message : "Something went wrong"});
             })
        })

        passport.serializeUser((user , done)=>{
            done(null , user._id)
        })

        passport.deserializeUser((id ,done)=>{
            user.findById(id,(err,user)=>{
                done(err,user);
            })
        })
}


module.exports = init;
```

This is my main server file

```
require("dotenv").config();
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const expressLayout= require("express-ejs-layouts");
const app = express();
const PORT=process.env.PORT || 3000;
const url = process.env.CONNECTION;
const session = require("express-session");
const flash = require("express-flash");
const passport = require("passport");

// defining public and view path
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname,"./public");
const viewPath = path.join(__dirname,"/resources/views");



//setting database
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true ,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex:true,
    useFindAndModify:true,    
    useUnifiedTopology:true
})

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.once('open',()=>{
    console.log("Database COnnected Successfully");
}).catch(err =>{
    console.log("Connection failed");
})

// setting session and cookie 
app.use(session({
    secret:process.env.secret,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        maxAge:1000*60*60*24  // 24 hours
    }
  }));

// passport setting
const passportInit = require("./app/config/passport");
passportInit(passport);
app.use(passport.session());

// Global Middle ware
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}))
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());


app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.locals.session = req.session;
    next();
})

//setting template engine
app.set("views",viewPath);
app.set("view engine" , "ejs");
app.use(expressLayout);


require('./route/web')(app);

app.listen(PORT , ()=>{
    console.log(`Listening to Port ${PORT}`);
})
```

My server file

Comment: Probably this line is the problem `new LocalStrategy({usernameField:'email'})`, the close parentheses should be removed. It should be `new LocalStrategy({usernameField:'email'}, callback)`

Comment: You are right, I got my result